# Trying to convert pacific time to UTC in SQL, keep running into error when declaring variable using datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, utc

I'm trying to get the correct date result, but I want to get the UTC time so my data would be correct. I want to get correct result for Saturday using UTC time, should I use `getdate()`?

This is the query partial:

```
declare @STARTDATE datetime = '07-03-2021 00:00:01'
declare @ENDDATE datetime = '07-03-2021 23:59:59'

select dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, getutcdate(), getdate()), @STARTDATE) as utc_stardate,dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, getutcdate(), getdate()), @endDATE) as utc_enddate
where repackagingtime between utc_stardate and utc_enddate
```

The error say:

> Must declare scalar variable

How do I fix it?

Update:

I didn't declare it first, but should I set as varchar?

like this?

```
declare @utc_enddate datetime
```

But after I applied changed, data from every day is now blank

Comment: If you want UTC wouldn't you use [`GETUTCDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Never declare a date as a varchar. If you need to include timezone information then use a `datetimeoffset `. Otherwise `datetime2`. Although what you are doing appears to be only using dates, in which case use a `date` datatype.

Comment: As a general rule I wouldn't use `between` I would use `where repackagingtime >= utc_stardate and repackagingtime < utc_enddate` and I would define both `utc_stardate` and  `utc_enddate` as a `date` not a `datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the utc date variables as a DATE datatype

You can convert a timezone to utc like this (est to utc). Just replace getdate() with your variable date.

```sql
DECLARE @UTCSTART DATE

SET @UTCSTART = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

Comment: Can you please re-write your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: can you please re-write your answer? I figured out why, but should I declare the new pseudo time as varchar or datetime?

Comment: Your variable should be a date datatype